# JSF and JPA best practice

Tags: jsf, jpa

I've a little experience with JSF and I would like to know the best practice to build a classic crud application with search capabilities. In particular I 'm in doubt about this last one; I've a form where the user type the object id; I've all my entities mapped with jpa and the relating facade session bean. But in the jsf page how could I read the parameter, call the finder method and then display the object properties?
Shall I use a servlet that get the object and store it in the request scope and access to that eith JSF EL?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a servlet. Just inject the session facade / EJB by `@EJB` in managed bean and call it in the bean action method and then display it the usual JSF/EL way in the result page.

View:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.search}" />
    <h:commandButton value="search" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty bean.result}">
    <p>#{bean.result.someProperty}</p>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Model:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private String search; // +getter +setter
    private Data result; // +getter

    @EJB
    private DataFacade dataFacade;

    public void submit() {
        result = dataFacade.find(search);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks; but I'm in the situation I have to display a single Object. I suppose I could replace the list() method with findById(int id) method, but how to get the parameter? I don't want to choose the object from a list.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you're asking. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Great! Many thanks. It's a new approac with I'm not too much familiar. I have to remove the jsp/servlet pattern from my mind.